# How to detect an ajax call on Facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I want to develop a chrome extension that replace some text on facebook but once the user scroll the ajax appear, so the newly ajax loaded text doesn't get change. I tried on() to bind but failed. So I'm thinking every time if there is ajax I fire my event again.

But I can't find any method to detect an ajax happened in a page using jquery :(

I tried

```
$('body').on(function(){
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        /* special ajax here */
        alert('test');
    }
});
```

not working

Comment: jQuery has global ajax handlers, such as `$.ajaxStart`, but I doubt facebook is using jQuery for their ajax calls.

Comment: @adeneo if it's not jquery then it's ajax, jquery can't catch an ajax? I doubt they didn't use ajax though..

Comment: Huh? I'm not saying facebook isn't using ajax, just that they aren't using jQuery, and that would mean XMLHttpRequest. Of course, there's also sockets and server sent events.

Comment: So now that you've added code, you're using `on` without an event, and what the heck is that PHP doing in a Chrome extension ?

Comment: @adeneo even I put that outside the on(), it detect nothing, that's why I debug with an on()..

Comment: You can't put that on the outside or the inside, its PHP code, not javascript code, you cannot mix and match the two

Comment: And you can't really put serverside code like PHP in a browser extension at all ?

Comment: @PatrickEvans LOL it's PHP! I just realised fuhhhhh funny

Answer (score 1):

to detect AJAX calls on a webpage you have to inject the code directly in that page and then call the `.ajaxStart` or `.ajaxSuccess`

Example:

```
// To Successfully Intercept AJAX calls, we had to embed the script directly in the Notifications page
var injectedCode = '(' + function() {
    $('body').ajaxSuccess(function(evt, request, settings) {
        if (evt.delegateTarget.baseURI == 'URL to check against if you want') {
            // do your stuff
        }
    });
} + ')();';
// Inserting the script into the page
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = injectedCode;
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can detect any AJAX calls with the following jQuery event handler which only works on the `document` element.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    alert('I'm making an AJAX call!!!');
});
```

You could also watch the 'Network' tab in developer tools.

Comment: I tried use this before, and when I scrolled the feed, doesn't appear in facebook..

Comment: Only would work if jQuery was the one actually making the ajax requests, facebook doesn't use jquery

Comment: Just answering the question, guys. One would have to assume that if you're going to use jQuery to detect the AJAX call, that jQuery would be the one performing the AJAX call.. ya know? Otherwise, this question and it's title make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @PatrickEvans so how could I catch the ajax? I checked the network tab, it fall under XHR, does that mean pure ajax?

Comment: @user3522749 Yes, XHR is an AJAX call.

Comment: Well, the question states that the OP is trying to catch ajax calls made by Facebook in an extension, so it's actually pretty much given that jQuery **is not** the one making the ajax calls, hence why I posted it as a comment under the question.

Comment: @user3522749,you would have to deminify their scripts and find which one does the xhr requests and find a way to hook into their api

Comment: hook into? how? I thought it would work with a normal js detection? I also tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783463/javascript-detect-ajax-requests but nothing happend